# Is there a package management system for shell scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there a package system (think `npm`, `cpan`, etc.) for shell scripts? Specifically, on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/bpkg/bpkg/ can be installed with:

```
curl -Lo- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpkg/bpkg/master/setup.sh" | bash
```

and lets you install packages like:

```
bpkg install term -g
```

Packages are just Git repositories with a `package.json` at top-level.

Comment: Worth noting that this is not specific only to Ubuntu.  This package manager will work with OS X and other Linux distros as well.

Comment: @davidcondrey yup, long live POSIX :-)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no such package / sharing tools for shell scripts... In my opinion, because there is not just one scripting language (you were probably thinking of `bash`, but other shells exist), and also because the task a shell script has to accomplish is often very specific.

Actually, you can think of the set of gnu tools (sed, awk, grep, etc...) as a set of basic (or more complex) tools, which are distributed as deb packages...

Nevertheless, you can find some examples on the net, like the list on [this blog post](http://dberkholz.com/2011/04/07/bash-shell-scripting-libraries/)...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sparrow](https://sparrowhub.org) - this is a script distribution system for Linux platforms.

Comment: Hi Eliah! Sorry for the inconvenience , my hosting provider has issues, now https://sparrowhub.org is accessible. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks